# Bootstrap cannot find symfony/stimulus-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bootstrap-5, webpack-encore

## Context

I am learning Symfony through "ENI learning" course "*Learn to Develop web applications with PHP and Symfony (2nd edition)*", by Yves ROCAMORA.

In the section "Webpack Encore", he explains how to use Sass and Vue.js to preprocess CSS and Javascript.

However, I am unable to make Webpack-Encore work alongside Bootstrap.

## The Problem

- I used `symfony new --webapp` to create the structure of the application.
- Then, `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` to install Webpack Encore.
- I installed `sass-loader`, `node-sass` and `bootstrap` with `npm`. `npm install` returns a clean installation.
- I did modify webpack.config.js to enable Sass loader.

**When I run `npm run watch`, I am confronted by the following error:**

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                  9:54:06

Module build failed: Module not found:
"./assets/bootstrap.js" contains a reference to the file "@symfony/stimulus-bundle".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.
```

## What am I expecting

`npm run watch` should correctly build the application.

## What I tried

First of all, I tried using composer to install the missing package, but it appears that stimulus-bundle is part of Webpack-Encore, and it already is on my project.

I noticed that the guide had a different `package.json`: mine was missing `@hotwired/stimulus` and `@symfony/stimulus-bridge`, so I tried to install them with composer, but those package cannot be installed this way. I even tried to add them manually (it is a bad habit, right?), and then run a `npm install`, but `npm run watch` still fails with the same error statement.

After cleaning my project and then punctiliously following each and every step of the guide, I still get the same error.

## Edit

The problem encountered was that I was using Symfony 7.0.1, while this method works for Symfony 6.

Comment: Symfony version? There are significant differences between v5 & v6 for webpack-encore and stimulus bundles.

Comment: @craigh I am using symfony 7.0.1, while the ressource I am using is for symfony 6.

I tried to build the application using symfony 6.4.1, and it does work. Thanks.

I will search for a solution using symfony 7.

Comment: Symfony 6+ will require symfony/stimulus-bridge separately from webpack-encore bundle. symfony/stimulus-bridge didn't exist before Symfony 6 and its stimulus functions were included in webpack-encore bundle.

Comment: @craigh  but why such error occurs in fresh installation? It will come with correctly updated bootstrap.js

Comment: I had the same problem. I guess it's because of asset-mapper. It is installed by default, and probably interferes with encore. So i removed it and tried installing it again. This time it actually updated the package.json to include "file:vendor/symfony/ux-turbo/assets". But "stimulus-bundle" was still missing. So i've added it like this to package.json:
"@symfony/stimulus-bundle": "file:vendor/symfony/stimulus-bundle/assets",

Force install and then it started working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and i think i now know why. The "--webapp" option installs "Asset Mapper" as default. This will be in conflict with the recipes from Encore. Symfony Flex does not know how to deal with that. So you have two options:

1. Remove everything related to AssetMapper

or

2. Just start a new project without --webapp option

I did the latter, and so far there are no errors when starting "npm run watch". Also, when adding "ux-turbo" it properly updated the "package.json" with the new packages. This didn't happen with Asset Mapper, and whatever its companions are, still around.

Please be aware, that starting the project without webapp option, will install the absolute bare bones of the project. You will have to add components like "template", "MakerBundle" and others yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently and resolved it thanks to a friend. I wanted to use Symfony UX Autocompletion.

From a blank project, I executed these commands :

```bash
symfony new my_project
cd my_project
composer require webapp

composer remove symfony/asset-mapper
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
composer require symfony/stimulus-bundle
composer require symfony/ux-autocomplete

npm install -f
npm run build
```

**To solve the problem I did these commands and steps :**

- Check if the package "@symfony/stimulus-bridge" is installed in `package.json`
- In `assets/app.js` add the line `import './bootstrap.js';`
- In `assets/bootstrap.js` change the **bundle** to **bridge** > `import { startStimulusApp } from '@symfony/stimulus-bridge';`
- In `webpack.config.js` add the line `.enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')` to import the controllers file
- Build again

```bash
rm -rf node_modules
npm i -f
npm run build
```

Idk if some steps are useless, but it works for me even on Symfony 6.4 and 7.0.

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77858819/7998119
- https://symfony.com/bundles/StimulusBundle/current/index.html

Comment: Worked for me with Symfony 7.0.4, thanks !
I think what did the trick was :
In assets/bootstrap.js change the bundle to bridge : 
import { startStimulusApp } from '@symfony/stimulus-bridge';