# Symfony 6.4 use encore webpack instead asset mapper

Tags: symfony, symfony-assetmapper, symfony-wepback-encore

In Symfony version 6.4 for using css and javascript is deault use symfony/asset-mapper. But in my application I try use Webpack Encore instead asset-mapper but in javasctipt console i see error

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module
```

How I completely disable asset-mapper or completely remove and use Webpack Encore?

Comment: after `composer remove symfony/asset-mapper`  run `npm install` and `npm run dev` I have teh error in console `Uncaught ReferenceError: startStimulusApp is not defined`

Comment: I have webpack-encore-bundle installed before I remove asset-mapper ?

Comment: I undestand the problem was taht I have installed Symfony version 6.4 with default asset-mapper an than I install webpack_encore_budnle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's not more than:

`composer remove symfony/asset-mapper`.

and then:

`composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`

Flex takes care of creating and deleting all the necessary files, and update the necessary templates.

I'm able to do this:

```bash
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:6.4.99 test-project
cd test-project
git init && git add . && git commit -m 'initial'
composer req webapp
git add . && git commit -m 'install webapp meta-pack'
composer remove symfony/asset-mapper
git add . && git commit -m 'remove asset-mapper'
composer req symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
git add . && git commit -m 'require webpack-encore'
npm install
git add . && git commit -m 'install node dependencies'
```

perfectly fine (I just copy-pasted the above on the terminal and ran it without issues).

The only I found to need doing after completing these steps is to remove `assets/vendor`. The mere existence of this directory and its contents shouldn't impact negatively your webpack-encore application, but they are not needed/used if you are not using the Asset Mapper component.

The two packages are mutually incompatible. If you install webpack-encore-bundle on top of a project that already includes asset-mapper, and then remove one of the two, the recipes may trip themselves, because they handle overlapping concerns, and leave you with a bit of a mess.